# is it posible to have all items in parent div in in columns

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div and i want all items in this div to be shown in the same row.

Here is my html.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent-div">
        <div class="item1">1</div>
        <div class="item2">2</div>
        <div class="item3">3</div>
        <div class="item4">4</div>
        <div class="item5">5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want them to always show in rows even when the parent div is not big enough.

Comment: Is it possible to use a table instead? And then inside each `<td>` element you'd add your divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **flex** for `.parent-div` rules. Add this to your css:

```
.parent-div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```css
.parent-div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent-div">
        <div class="item1">1</div>
        <div class="item2">2</div>
        <div class="item3">3</div>
        <div class="item4">4</div>
        <div class="item5">5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the parent div flex:

```
.parent-div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```css
.parent-div {
display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parent-div">
        <div class="item1">1</div>
        <div class="item2">2</div>
        <div class="item3">3</div>
        <div class="item4">4</div>
        <div class="item5">5</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how is your answer different from my answer?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Because you originally gave an answer to display all the children as `inline-block` and it seems you changed your answer to match mine.

Comment: jaja, no, I did not repeat after you. Later I read this from the author's question - *"I want them to always show in rows even when the parent div is not big enough"*. And gave the answer with a `flex` for the parent.